# Remover espaço em branco de um Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

Estou precisando manipular uma imagem e identificar os objetos dentro dela.
Porém a resposta que recebo vem com espaço em branco e eu não estou conseguindo tratar para retirar esses espaços em brancos.

Código:

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2

executing_path = os.getcwd()

detector = ObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsRetinaNet()
detector.setModelPath( os.path.join (executing_path, "resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5"))
detector.loadModel()
custom_objects = detector.CustomObjects(bottle=True)
detections = detector.detectCustomObjectsFromImage(custom_objects=custom_objects,input_image=os.path.join(executing_path, "mercado1.jpg"), 
                                             output_image_path=os.path.join(executing_path, "mercado111.jpg"),
                                             minimum_percentage_probability=10, display_percentage_probability=True, display_object_name=False)

for eachObject in detections:    
    y = eachObject["box_points"]
    print(y)
```

Resposta:

```
[ 990   33 1011   91]
[970  52 990  91]
[ 986   49 1006   92]
[1011   32 1040   91]
```

Como gostaria que ficasse:

```
[990 33 1011 91]
[970 52 990 91]
[986 49 1006 92]
[1011 32 1040 91]
```

Estou usando o Imageai para buscar os objetos da imagem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize uma função para remover espaços desnecessários.

```
def remove_unneeded_spaces(x):
    x = str(x)
    x = re.sub(" +", " ", x)  # Remove espaços repetidos.
    x = re.sub("\[ ", "[", x) # Remove espaços após o [.
    x = re.sub(" \]", "]", x) # Remove espaços antes do ].
    x = re.sub(" \[", "[", x) # Remove espaços antes do [.
    x = re.sub("\] ", "]", x) # Remove espaços após o ].
    return x
```

E então, ao invés disso:

```
print(y)
```

Você usa isso:

```
print(remove_unneeded_spaces(y))
```